# Using mocha-loader for webpack with electron

Tags: javascript, webpack, mocha.js, electron

I'd like to use mocha to test my electron app. I'm using the following loader to process my tests:

```
{
    test: /(\.js)$/,
    loaders: ['mocha', 'babel'],
    include: [path.join(__dirname, 'tests')]
}
```

And, my `target` is set to `electron`. My main application bundle builds just fine. But, when I build the test bundle, I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./tests/index.js
Module build failed: Error: Unsupported target environment electron
    at Object.module.exports.pitch (/Users/mparrott/dev/architect-editor/node_modules/mocha-loader/index.js:33:9)
```

And, sure enough, the [mocha source](https://github.com/webpack/mocha-loader/blob/master/index.js#L13) doesn't seem to support `electron`.

How should I use mocha to test my electron app?